# JavaFX: why text is blurred?

Tags: java, javafx

Im starting with JavaFX, but immediately noticed that labels are blurred
(Do you see these pink edging around letters?)

I tried changing fonts, size, weight, but same...

It's offending to the eye, looks bulky, is there any way to make it appear without blurring effect?

[image]

I'm using OpenFx 13, tried with previous versions of JavaFx.

**scene.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.openjfx.FXMLController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="label" text="Label" />
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

**FXMLController**

```
package org.openjfx;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;

public class FXMLController {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    public void initialize() {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        label.setFont(Font.font("Menlo", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
        label.setText("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + "\nRunning on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
    }    
}
```

**MainApp**

```
package org.openjfx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Gradle");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the LCD anti-aliasing on the **MainApp** :

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
    System.setProperty("prism.lcdtext", "false");
    ... The rest of your code ...
}
```